# Copy text from one control to another whilst typing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 controls on a Form, and I want that whilst I'm entering text in 1 control, the same text is entered in the 2 control immediately.

I've tried the following events:

`KeyDown`,
`KeyPress`,
`KeyUp`,
`PreviewKeyDown`

But they all have the same effect, ie. the second control is one character behind. These controls are bound to a bindingsource.

Is there any other event that I can use or is there any other way to do this?

EDIT:

I just saw the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: you can try textchanged event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextChanged` event. Define this event for your first control say text box, and in this event, set the text of your second control.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```